# difference between Routers in Backbone.js and routers in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, rubygems

I'm new to the Ruby on rails, and I'm learning Backbone.js also to use as front-end framework.

Can anyone tell me the difference between Routers in "Backbone.js" and routers in Ruby on rails?

Comment: They are totally, completely different things. Apples and oranges. Just because they happen to share a name doesn't make them meaningfully comparable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Backbone router lets you navigate within a Backbone app, matching URL path patterns to specified methods. This is unlike the Rails router which responds to actual HTTP requests. A Backbone route does not refresh the page.

For instance if I embed a link to "/posts" in a page on www.myapp.com, clicking on it will change the URL to www.myapp.com/#/posts, which in turn calls the method defined as "posts" in my Backbone router. Inside this method I would want to create a new PostsIndexView and render it in the router's DOM element.

Take a look at this resource if you haven't already: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/

Comment: Not quite... The Rails Router takes an HTTP request and instantiates a Controller to call the method needed. This produces an HTTP response with a new HTML view, moving you to a different web page (or in some cases refreshing the current page with new data). The Backbone router doesn't produce an HTTP response. It simply causes DOM elements on the current page to change so it looks like a different web page.